# Allocate only one dimension for a 2D array in fortran

Tags: arrays, fortran

Suppose I have a 2D array A(:,2) where only the size of first dimension is unknown.
Is it possible to allocate only for the first dimension of A ? 
If not, I have to go with " allocate(A(n,2)) " each time by treating A as A(:,:).

Comment: No, you can't 'allocate' an array one rank at a time.  Perhaps if you explained why you want to do this (to my dull senses) bizarre thing someone might be able to offer a solution which satisfies both your requirement and the rules of Fortran.

Comment: If you know a dimension of the array in advance, then I'm guessing `A(:,1)` and `A(:,2)` refer to quantities of different type, say some x- and y-values. It might be better then, mainly for readability, to declare the arrays separately, e.g., `x_data(:)` and `y_data(:)`. But it's hard to say without further information.

Comment: correct, you can't declare an array as `.. dimension (:,2), allocatable`.  So even if you know a particular dimension at the time you write the program, you will have to assign that dimension with the allocate statement, as you wrote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the second dimension is always of size 2, you could create a data type with two variables and then allocate an array of them:

```
program main
    implicit none

    type two_things
        integer :: first
        integer :: second
    end type two_things

    type(two_things), dimension(:), allocatable :: A

    allocate(A(100))

    A(1)%first = 1
    A(1)%second = 2

    print*, A(1)%first, A(1)%second, shape(A)

    deallocate(A)

end program main
```

Comment: This is a nice and reasonable way to do it.  Thank you.

Comment: It depends on what you need to do, but keep in mind that having a 100 instances of a two-component type might not be as efficient as having two 100-element arrays or one rank 2 array.