# Rank-2 Allocatable Array Declaration With One Dimension Fixed

Tags: arrays, fortran

I try to build the following code:

```
integer, parameter :: N = 2
real, dimension(1:N,:), allocatable :: ArrayA
```

this leads to the error:

> bad array specification for an **explicitly shaped** array.

I tried doing it the other way around:

```
integer, parameter :: N = 2
real, dimension(:,1:N), allocatable :: ArrayA
```

This time, the error is as follows:

> Bad specification for **deferred shape** array

My question is two-fold:

Why are the two cases leading to different errors? How do I declare a 2D array that is allocatable in one direction but fixed in the other?

Comment: An allocatable array should be declared with all dimensions as ":".   Even though you might know the values of some dimensions when you write the program, you will have to provide them when you allocate the array.

Comment: Related and possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29506872/allocate-only-one-dimension-for-a-2d-array-in-fortran. However, the current question is written much better.

Answer (score 2):

> Why are the two cases leading to different errors?

I expect it's because the compiler reads lines from left to right.  So when it gets

```
real, dimension(1:N,:), allocatable :: ArrayA
```

it reads this much

```
real, dimension(1:N,
```

and sees that it is reading the declaration of an *explicitly shaped array*, then reads `:` and complains.

Likewise, when reading

```
real, dimension(:,1:N), allocatable :: ArrayA
```

it sees what it determines to be the declaration of a *deferred shape array*

```
real, dimension(:,
```

and expects another `:`.

> How do I declare a 2D array that is allocatable in one direction but
>   fixed in the other?

*EDIT: after OP's further comments*

What's wrong with this ?

```
integer, parameter :: N = 2
integer :: m
real, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: arrayA
...
! get a value for m
allocate(arrayA(m,N))
```

Comment: The method highlighted in the answer linked by VladimirF's comment isn't extendable to higher dimensions, is there any alternate you are aware of? (I mean that if i change the 2d to 3d, it requires declaration of a new attribute in the type declaration - unlike my imagined Array declaration where i can set N = 3 in this new case).

Comment: I meant a rank-2 array whose fixed dimension i would like to parametrise. so in the question, i have the dimension declaration as `(:,1:N)` where my parameter is `N`, i want to be able to change this `N` before runtime but not have to change my code otherwise.

Comment: @anuvaramban Just allocate every dimension in `allocate`. That's how it is meant to do. Don't try to invent complicated kludges.

Comment: @VladimirF the issue i have with this is that i don't know how large my other dimension will be beforehand and moreover, the number of elements in the other dimension is dynamic even after i allocate.

Comment: @anuvaramban That is not possible in Fortran.