# Passing 2D array of unknown size to function in Fortran

Tags: fortran

Trying to input a 2D array with an unknown size, n, in one of its dimensions as the input to a function. So, the input will be (n, 3) and output (n, 1). These will represent n Cartesian coordinates.

So far have been trying:

```
function IterativeHarmonics(l, m, x)
   real :: IterativeHarmonics
   integer, intent(in) :: l, m
   real, intent(in) :: x(:,3)

   IterativeHarmonics = x(1,3)
end function IterativeHarmonics
```

But this gives the errors

```
Error: Bad specification for deferred shape array at (1)
```

and

```
Error: Function ‘x’ at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
```

Comment: What are you trying to say with `real, intent(in) :: x(:,3)`, and are you sure your compiler doesn't complain about that line?

Comment: @francescalus Trying to declare the array, seen similar before (for a 1D array of size 3 `real(dp), intent(in) :: x(3)`. Was assuming the : would make it work for 2D? 

You are right though, I did miss an error `Error: Bad specification for deferred shape array at (1)`

Comment: I was having just this same error, didn't realise I couldn't do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with [deferred-shape arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44060210/3157076), we cannot just partially assume the shape of an array.

That is,

```
real x(:,3)
```

is not allowed, even where we know the extent of the second dimension will always be `3`.  We must assume like

```
real x(:,:)
```

If you want to use assumed-shape arrays, but insist on the second extent being of a specific value, you'll need to add your own checks.  You can, of course, use an explicit shape where the first extent is passed:

```
real x(n,3)   ! n accessible somehow, probably as dummy
```

(The error about `x` being a function and of implicit type follows on from the faulty declaration.)

Comment: Thanks! I think I get where I was confused now.

Comment: Good answer, +1. I decided to go for the second suggested solution, as I'm writing my function to be used in ```f2py``` so I can get the required values for ```n``` and pass them into the function.